# Preserving whitespace in a String when using as a command line argument

Tags: java, whitespace, args

I am attempting to write an GUI in Java that can send a users input to other files for processing, which is done using command line arguments. This works fine unless a user tries to send a string with whitespace, as they are interpreted as separate arguments. Here is an example:

```
public String exampleMethod(String userInput, String fileName)
{

    try 
    {
        String output = "";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./directory/" + fileName + " " + userInput);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            output = output + line;
        }
        return output;
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "ERROR: I/O Exception";
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces are used to separate argument. User should uses quotes (").

Comment: I actually feel like an idiot, spent so long trying to work out the problem that that never occurred to me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Java's built-in [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to do this. Something like:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("./directory/" + fileName, userInput).start();
```

Alternatively, for something more robust, have a look at [Apache's Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html) framework, though the code necessary is a bit more verbose.